# Is it possible to use app bundle for android smartphones but not for Android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, android-app-bundle

I am just considering to use the app bundle for my application. Right now I am a developer who is developing an application for Smartphones and Tablets. Another developer is creating my application for Android TV. I am using Android Studio (java, kotlin) and he is using some javascript framework.

My question is: If I start to upload my app to google play using the app bundle is there any chance to affect Android TV build? I'd like to avoid the situation when Android TV takes some ask for smartphones but not for Android TV.

Comment: Hi, did you end up finding a good way to deploy different bundles with same package name to Android TV and tablets ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are currently publishing two separate APKs (one for phone+tablet, and one for TV) with the same package name and are releasing them together, is that correct?

If so you can definitely replace the phone/tablet APK with an App Bundle and keep releasing a separate APK for TV.

Comment: Thats true, I have two separate APKs. And thanks for your response

Comment: What if I want to merge the TV Apk into the app bundle? Been reading and searching a lot, but couldn't find anything specific. Any help is really appreciated.